# Is Entity Framework tied to SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, ms-access

What if I want to connect to Oracle, MySQL or even MS Access ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  It uses the ADO.Net "provider" model to plug in a database provider to give access to any third party database.

A list of available [third party EF providers is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx).

And [here's an example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider) of a prototype Oracle provider with source code.

Comment: For Oracle it says not for production :)

Can't see Provider for MS Access, why people always forget Access.

Comment: Yeah I know it's not.  I just linked it just because it has source code.  The idea behind the provider model is that it should be relatively straightforward to implement ;)

Comment: @programmernovice: If you need Entity Framework, you probably need a better DBMS than Access... Access is OK for simple desktop needs, but it's definitely not a first class DBMS

Comment: @Thomas  Define simple and desktop needs.

Comment: @Tony Entity Framework was designed to work with a full-blown RDBMS with advanced record locking mechanisms and its own engine.  Access is a file-based system suitable for desktop applications, not n-tier multi-user systems.

Comment: n-tiers has nothing to do with record locking, and access can be usefull to prototype an application before switching to a server db.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem with the Entity Framework, is that Microsoft does not provide “providers” for 3rd party databases it's self.  At present I don’t think Oracle provides a “provider” for the Entity Framework, so if you wish to use the Entry Framework with Oracle you have to buy in a “provider”.